# Parse the values from CSV file as JSON through Jquery AJAX 

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I am trying to get JSON data from Yahoo's Finance API.

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback", function(data) {
// I am parsing JSON string using data here 
});
```

Problem is when when stock is close, I need to show last trade values. I found a link which returns values as a CSV file. So I need to download it and parse it with jQuery.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback", function(data) {


if(data.query.results.quote.DaysLow == null && data.query.results.quote.DaysHigh == null){

    //When stock is closed this section works
    var date = data.query.results.quote.LastTradeDate;
    var datesplit = date.split('/');


        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WRC&a="+ datesplit[1] +"&b="+ datesplit[0] + "&c="+ datesplit[2] +"&d="+ datesplit[1] +"&e="+ datesplit[0] +"&f="+ datesplit[2] +"&g=d&ignore=.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
        }
        });
}
else{
  //When stock is not closed this section works
  //There is no problem in this section

}       
});
```

This is the error message I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WRC&a=18&b=9&c=2012&d=18&e=9&f=2012&g=d&ignore=.csv.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can you please help me for downloading CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need of ajax you can simply call it like

```
    document.location.href = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WRC&a="+ datesplit[1] +"&b="+ datesplit[0] + "&c="+ datesplit[2] +"&d="+ datesplit[1] +"&e="+ datesplit[0] +"&f="+ datesplit[2] +"&g=d&ignore=.csv";
```

It will not reload page

Comment: Nope this is not i am looking for, i need to parse the json data and show it in some labels, this code just downloads the file.. Anyway thank you for comment

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using any server side script

eg :-

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your-server-side-file.php",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

and in that server file `your-server-side-file.php` process the csv file parse the value. return with your own format.

For example php csv file parsing http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php